# Is there a way to move selector with more than one cell selected?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to move the selector (3 cells selected in the example below) with arrow keys. It is possible to move with one cell selected, can I do it with more than one cells? Thanks. Note: I don't want to move or copy contents of the cells. I just want to move the selector (big rectangular box) as easy as moving a single cell selector. (The question in the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/238449/how-to-move-selection-in-excel) is not answered yet either, and the offered solutions what I was not looking for).

[image]

Comment: To move it left or right, you can use Shift-Arrow, Tab, then Shift-Arrow again.  Not sure if there is a way to move up and down.

Comment: @Bandersnatch – you reminded me that it worked that way! I already found out a way for vertical movement, too.

Comment: Actually I tried Shift+Arrow tab before posting the question, and other alternatives too, but it didn't work. and I still can't move it. it is resized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move selection in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/238449/how-to-move-selection-in-excel) The OP found it after answering. I should have seen it earlier.

Comment: Downvoting for originally misleading question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above image: If you mean moving selection of C3:C5 to become D3:D5, then it is possible in somewhat cumbersome way as shown in Bandersnatch's comment.

[image]

**Moving N cells right [left]:** (follow either normal text or text in [brackets])

1. Highlight a cell in leftmost [rightmost] column of selection using <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> if not already done.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> [<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>] N times.
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> [<kbd>Tab</kbd>] once.
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> [<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>] N times again.

**Moving N cells down [up]:** (follow either normal text or text in [brackets]

1. Highlight a cell in top [bottom] row of selection using <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> if not already done.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> [<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>] N times.
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> [<kbd>Enter</kbd>] once.
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> [<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>] N times again.

Comment: This command for resizing, I guess. What I am seeking is moving the selector which is the size of C3:C5 here without moving its content or changing it size across the data.

Comment: @user761065 – these sequences use resizing for moving, that's the trick. Position of highlighted cell in selection is important when you are doing this, it affects behavior of arrows. If you have a problem in any step, let me know.

Comment: I found similar question  https://superuser.com/questions/238449/how-to-move-selection-in-excel and there they suggest using ASAP Utilities  which I downloaded and tried already. It does what I say, it would be nice to have an excel way of doing this too actually.

Comment: @user761065 – I added a video for you. It shows how the selection is moving. Are you sure you were following the steps (including work with highlighted cell) correctly?

Comment: yes I know this. but it is not really practical as moving a single cell selector.

Comment: @user761065 – but if you know that, why you were asking as if you did not know? This could save time of persons attempting to comment or answer.

Comment: I think this is not a solution to apply on a large spreadsheet with lots of data. I was looking for a way to move the selector which is bigger than a single cell at ease.

Comment: @user761065 – sure, but we, the other users, know only what is written. So the question as it we could see it, was addressing general way and was answered in the same way. If you want to ask something very different when answers exist, it is better idea to create a new question ("I want this but not that way") and maybe accept the existing question as it is.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the range is discontiguous - e.g. if you select multiple cells via Ctrl-click (Cmd-click on Mac) rather than selecting one contiguous block by dragging.